# iText: Can PdfTemplate of one Document object be used in another Document Object?

Tags: templates, itext, document

I am using iText2.1.2 and my requirement is to use the template created from Document1 object onto Document2 object.

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class TestITextTemplate {

public TestITextTemplate() {
    super();
}

public static final String DEST = "D:\\Doc1.pdf";
public static final String DEST1 = "D:\\Doc2.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException   {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new TestITextTemplate().createPdf();
}

public void createPdf() {
    try {
        //1st Document Object.
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DEST);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template =
            contentByte.createTemplate(document.getPageSize().getWidth(), document.getPageSize().getHeight());
        Graphics2D g2 =
            template.createGraphicsShapes(document.getPageSize().getWidth(), document.getPageSize().getHeight());
        template.setLineWidth(Float.parseFloat(2 + "") * 0.72f);
        g2.drawString("Test String", 100, 120);
        g2.dispose();

        contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);
        writer.releaseTemplate(template);

        document.close();

        //2nd Document Object.
        Document document1 = new Document();
        FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(DEST1);
        PdfWriter writer1 = PdfWriter.getInstance(document1, fos1);
        document1.open();
        PdfContentByte contentByte1 = writer1.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template1 =
            contentByte1.createTemplate(document1.getPageSize().getWidth(), document1.getPageSize().getHeight());
        Graphics2D g21 =
            template1.createGraphicsShapes(document1.getPageSize().getWidth(), document1.getPageSize().getHeight());
        template1.setLineWidth(Float.parseFloat(1 + "") * 0.72f);
        g21.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, 120, 400, 120));
        g21.dispose();

        contentByte1.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);//Adding template of 1st Document object to 2nd Document object.
        contentByte1.addTemplate(template1, 50, 50); 

        writer1.releaseTemplate(template);
        writer1.releaseTemplate(template1);

        document1.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When the contents of the **template1** is added after adding the **template** to the **contentByte1**, the contents of **template** is being overwritten by **template1**.

Is this not possible? How should this work ideally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't expect any answers to questions about a version that dates from [May 16, 2008](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/212). You should upgrade. Please stop using iText 2.1.2 even if you are working on a legacy project. One would expect that some maintenance was done on a project that has been active for more than 7 years.

Comment: I am facing the same issue even with iText5.4.0.

Comment: In both cases, you are making a logical error.

Comment: I will be grateful if you can point it out and help me. I have just started to progress in building reports using iText.

Comment: If you just started working with iText, please make sure always to use a recent version.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the first `PdfTemplate` instance (`template`), you create a dependency on the first `PdfWriter`.

```
PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(...);
```

This dependency is necessary because you're adding content to the `template` object that requires resources. These resources are written to the `writer` object as you go.

As soon as you close your first `Document` instance (`document.close();`), the `writer` is also closed. The `template` is released implicitly (you didn't have to do this explicitly) and you're done.

Then you create a second `PdfTemplate` instance (`template1`), and you create a dependency on a second `PdfWriter` (`writer1`). Again you add content to the `PdfTemplate` and again resources are written to the `PdfWriter`. These resources are all correctly referenced when you add to the content of `writer1`.

However: you are also trying to add `template` to the content of `writer1`. Common sense should tell you that his cannot work: the resources needed for `template` are written to `writer`. They are not present in `writer1`. Without the resources written to `writer`, you can never correctly add `template` to `writer1`.

The best way to work around this, is to create a small single-page in-memory PDF file with the resource you want to reuse. Reuse that small single-page using a `PdfImportedPage` object.